# Detect Double Click Globally in Windows

Tags: c#, c++, windows, visual-studio-2010, winapi

I want to write a Windows program that runs in the background and prints out the exact time (accurate to the millisecond) of when the next mouse double click event occurs. Specifically, I want the exact time at which I double click on a certain .exe file on my desktop. Is there a way of doing this, and if so, could you provide some simple sample code?

Comment: Does it have to be a double click, or the program being run? For the latter, I think there's some kind of shell hook you can use, but I've never used a shell one.

Comment: It would be much easier to wrap the exe, create your own exe that performs the printing and call the other exe.

Comment: @chris - I would like it to be the double click, since I want the time as soon as the CPU receives the instruction.

Comment: @Guvante - Do you mean to code a .exe which prints the time it was opened instead?

Comment: @JohnRoberts: Basically, attempting to hook into the way Windows executes a program (especially differentiating between different ways of running a program) is very difficult.

Comment: @JohnRoberts, If you can't be bothered to wait for the program to initialize, I'd really recommend not doing a bunch of extra work figuring out what was double clicked and instead waiting for the moment right after when the shell decides to open it. I'm fairly certain there's some aspect of `WH_SHELL` that tells you when it's decided it's going to run a file, and it would be a lot easier to check based off of that information.

Comment: Personally, I would look into hooking an appropriate Windows API function, perhaps CreateProcess.  Then, check against the incoming application name, if it matches your executable, log the time, and then pass through and let Windows do its thing.  Just be careful, because if you write a bad hook at this level, you might have to reboot to regain control of your system.

Comment: If one is going to downvote my question, I'd appreciate the common courtesy of knowing why so I may improve upon it. Otherwise, it serves little purpose.

Comment: @Guvante: How exactly is this not a real question? And in what sense is it ambiguous, vague, incomplete, or overly broad? You left a comment when the question was first posted, and made no indication then that the question was poor. I made it very clear what I was looking for, and the two answers and multiple comments (yours included) I received obviously indicate that people knew what I was talking about.

Comment: @JohnRoberts: I don't know what I voted for (the only feedback is the most common choice), I think I may have said Superusers/Serverfault, since I didn't feel you had shown you needed to code something. However I do agree that the question is incomplete. You didn't show that any coding was necessary to solve the problem, as shown by my "answer" being write a batch file. Additionally there is no code or other attempts to solve the problem, only the original problem. In either case it is a moot point, you received an answer anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably making a Windows hook is the best solution.
Check out the documentation on hooks.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632589%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

And check out this demo:

http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsdesktop/CppWindowsHook-06957865

Answer (score 0):

In some cases like silverlight you don't have mouse double click event so what you can do is check the time and position of mouse down and compair it with next mouse down time and position to simulate a double click action. it goes like this:

```
    double mouseVerticalPosition;
    double mouseHorizontalPosition;        
    DateTime clickedTime;
    bool IsSecondClick = false;


    void button_MouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
       {
           if(IsSecondClick)
           {

             IsSecondClick = false;
             if ((y - mouseVerticalPosition == 0) & y - mouseHorizontalPosition == 0) &
             clickedTime - DateTime.Now < SOMETIME )
             { 
               // mouse double click happenes
             }
           }
           else
           {
             IsSecondClick = true;
             clickedTime = DateTime.Now;
             mouseVerticalPosition = e.GetPosition(null).Y;
             mouseHorizontalPosition = e.GetPosition(null).X;               

           }
       }
```